# Elasticsearch date match in index name doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch

- Elasticsearch: `2.1`
- Timezone: `+0800`
- Index: `nginx-2015.12.18`
- Current Time: `2015-12-18 16:08`

According to [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date-math-index-names.html) following query will resolve to index `nginx-2015.12.18`

`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<nginx-{now/d}>/_search'`

But, in reality it gives

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"<nginx-now","index":"<nginx-now"}],"type":"index_not_found_exception","reason":"no such index","resource.type":"index_or_alias","resource.id":"<nginx-now","index":"<nginx-now"},"status":404}
```

---

curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

> ⋊> ~ curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'                                                                                                                                                                                             16:31:35

```
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
yellow open   nginx                5   1         18            0    120.7kb        120.7kb 
yellow open   wx-data-2015.12.18   5   1          2            0      9.6kb          9.6kb 
yellow open   nginx-2015.12.18     5   1          5            0       33kb           33kb
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the output you get when running `curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13665), This is what @javanna said,

> we had initially treated this as a bug and fixed it, but afterwards we
>   found out that the fix introduced a regression ([#14177](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/14177)), which made us
>   take a step back. Any slash that should not be used as a path
>   separator in a uri should be properly escaped, and it is wrong to try
>   and make distinctions between the different slashes on the server side
>   depending on what surrounds them, that heuristic is not going to fly
>   (in fact it didn't :) )
>
> We are going to revert the initial fix then, the solution to this
>   problem is to **escape the '/' in the url** like this: curl -XGET
>   `'localhost:9200/<logstash-{now%2Fd}>/animals/1'`. That is going to work
>   and didn't require any fix in the first place.

I also had to escape the `{}`, This worked for me on `ES 2.0`

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<nginx-\{now%2Fd\}>/_search'
```

Does this help?